# iOS how to create a block list from the contacts and block the calls of those in the list?

Tags: iphone, ios, call, block

Any idea guys? Can we do this using the available APIs? I want to get the contact list then select from people from there and block their calls if blocking of calls is turned on in my app. Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible until and unless your device is jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

You need to jailbreak the device and use the private APIs to achieve your requirements. It is not possible in non jailbroken devices as Apple will not allow this.