# Show Blocked Contacts using ABAddressBook

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

This question is for iOS 10 and Xcode 8. I know how to get user local address book contacts using ABAddressbook and show them in my app. What I was trying to do next are two things

- Show the user what contacts he/she has blocked himself
- Try see if I can block or unblock those contacts programmatically

The reason I am doing this is that as of now the only way to "block" a contact using native iOS app is to click on a contact, scroll down and click on block/unblock button. I was just trying to figure out if I can help the user quickly see all the contacts in their addresbook they have blocked and perhaps unblock/block one with one less tap using my app.

I have looked into callkit and that is not what I need. I am not creating a VOIP app nor do I need to create my own block list.

I have googled quite a bit and didn't find an answer for blocking / unblocking contacts using ABAddressbook which must mean its not possible. Suggestions?

Comment: Does iOS 10 have abadressbook concept?.If it has,why do we use contact framework?.

Answer (score 0):

In some way it is not possible till your device is **jailbroken** as [this says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601064/ios-how-to-create-a-block-list-from-the-contacts-and-block-the-calls-of-those-in) and also it is possible if we use **CallKit framework** as [Possible to programmatically block phone number in iOS source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884289/can-an-iphone-app-block-phone-calls).

[Apple document Says](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit?language=objc)

> The CallKit framework provides programmatic access to VoIP functionality, as well as call blocking and identification.